# Generate weighted random number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

What's the best way to produce a weighted die roll in Swift, given the following percentages?

```
var weight = [0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1]
```

e.g. There's a 10% chance it will roll a 1, 20% chance for a 2, etc.

Comment: I think the referenced thread should be what you are looking for. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the answer in Swift, so I'd post it. I should've been searching for "distribution" instead of "weighted"

Comment: I think both are valid terms. I just happened to know about this Q&A :)